# Adb does not recognize my HTC one m8

Tags: adb, android-sdk

I know about 51-android.rules file. I have created it manually. 
Here it is:

```
#HTC
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Then I restarted udev and still adb does not recognize my phone. But fastboot somehow does. Maybe I missed something. I have adb_usb.ini and added *0x0bb4* and still doesn't work.

This is the output of lsusb command:

> Bus 006 Device 005: ID 0bb4:0ff0 HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.)

One more important thing is that I can't go to usb debugging mode because my phone is soft bricked the only thing I can do is to go on fastboot mode.

Comment: Please show the relevant output of "lsusb" when your phone is plugged in.  This webpage was helpful for me some time ago : https://afterthoughtsoftware.com/posts/using-adb-with-wileyfox-swift

Comment: I think its not possible to use adb without debugging mode. So I just installed custom recovery mode with fastboot and from the custom recovery mode installed android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was right. Adb works ONLY in usb debugging mode. I installed custom recovery then Android. I turned my usb debugging on and it works. So there is nothing wrong with Ubuntu; it's an Android problem.